# Modifying a text file with php

Tags: php

I have two webpages a.php and b.php. The submitted values in texboxes will be written to a text file.

a.php :

```
 <html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

 $aa = $_POST['alpha'];

 $f = fopen("text.txt", "w");

 fwrite($f,$aa."\n");

 }
 else

 {
 $f= fopen("text.txt",'r');

  while ((!feof($f)) && ($found == 0)) {

  list($aa)=fscanf($f,"%f[^\n]");

   }

   }

  fclose($f);

   ?>
   <form action="a.php" name="Calculation" method="post">

   Alphabet: <INPUT TYPE ="TEXT" id="alph" Name "alpha"          VALUE="<?PHP print $aa; ?>">

   <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value ="Save Parameters">

    </form>

    </html>
```

and b.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit1'])) {

$bb = $_POST['beta'];

 file_put_contents("text.txt", $bb."\n" , FILE_APPEND);

 }

 else

 {

 $f= fopen("text.txt",'r');

 while ((!feof($f)) && ($found == 0)) {

 list($aa)=fscanf($f,"%f[^\n]");
  list($bb)=fscanf($f,"%f");
 }
 }

 fclose($f);

  ?>
 <form action="b.php" name="Calculation" method="post">

 Alphabet: <INPUT TYPE ="TEXT" id="betaa" Name ="beta" size="5"     VALUE="<?PHP print $bb; ?>">

 <Input Type = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" Value ="Save Parameters">

  </form>

  </html>
```

The codes work fine and the values in the text boxes will be written to a textfile if I enter the first valu in a.php text box and the second value in b.php textbox. For example if I put aa in the textbox of a.php and bb in the text box of b.php I will get

aa
bb

in my text file. However if I go back to my a.php file and put a new value in its text box I will loose bb. Is there a way to only change the value of the first line of the text box and keep the bb in second line of the text box?
 . The problem is that I will lose the values of my b.php script if I add a new value. I don't want to add to the number of lines in the text file. I was wondering if there is a way to rewrite on aa with cc for example.

Comment: you can use json function to manipulate with vars independently. Look my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting your file in `a.php` using the `w` switch.

Use the `a` switch to append.

```
$f = fopen("text.txt", "a");
```

Consult the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Or, do as you did in the other file (b.php) using [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents("text.txt", $bb."\n" , FILE_APPEND);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it does the same thing.

---

**Edit:**

> *"I have a webpage that has several text boxes that need to be filled and the values are saved in a text file when the submit button is hit. Then there is another webpage that has several text boxes as well that need to be filled out and the values will have to be added to the same text file.*
>
> *So if the user after pressing the submit button decides to change a value of one text box in a.php and then hit submit again I will lose all the information in bb.php unless I add more lines to my text file with the new information."*

An alternate method would be to use two seperate and different filenames while keeping what you have now.

Here is an example, and concatenating the files:

```
<?php 
$file1 = file_get_contents('file1.txt');
$file2 = file_get_contents('file2.txt');

$show_all = $file1 . $file2;

echo $show_all;
```

- I used [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) in this example, since I do not know how you are presently showing the content in your webpage.

**Sidenote:**

If you want to add a line break between both, use `<br>`.

```
$show_all = $file1 . "<br>" . $file2;
```

or just a simple space:

```
$show_all = $file1 . " " . $file2;
```

Comment: I want to overwrite on aa and keep the number of lines in the text file to two. So when the user decides to change a value in a.php (for example from aa to cc)  he can see  cc bb instead of aa bb. I don't want to add to the number of lines.

Comment: But I want to overwrite a value and do not want to see it anymore. Append will keep the old value and append a new value.

Comment: @MaryE TBH, at this point, am having difficulty understanding the question and I may have to delete my answer. Give me a few minutes. If I can't figure it out, I will as I said, delete my answer. I was certain that this is what you were looking for originally.

Comment: @MaryE However, can you not just combine both as one, rather than using two methods/files? If you were to tell me what the ultimate goal is, I may be able to offer an alternative. Because your a.php will certainly need to use the `a` switch, any which way. Using seperate inputs in one form/file could be an alternative also.

Comment: I have a webpage that has several text boxes that need to be filled and the values  are saved in a text file when the submit button is hit. Then there is another webpage that has several text boxes as well that need to be filled out and the values will have to be added to the same text file.So if the user after pressing the submit button decides to change a value of one text box in a.php and then hit submit again I will lose all the information in bb.php unless I add more lines to my text file with the new information.

Comment: @MaryE the only thing that comes to mind to me right now is, that you could use two different files and then just fetch both files and concatenate the variables used for them during the echos/outputs. Yet, a database would be much easier too.

Comment: @MaryE I made an edit and added an example of what I meant earlier. Please reload my answer and look near the end under **Edit:**.

Answer (score 1):

To change only some specific lines of your file you can use:

```
$file = "text.txt";
$aa = $_POST['alpha'];
$rows_of_file = file($file); // put your file in an array line by line
$rows_of_file[0] = $aa; // 0 indicate the first line of the file
file_put_contents($file, implode($rows_of_file)); //rewrite the content with the new changes
```

So you can change *aa* in *cc*, and *bb* remains unchanged

Comment: If you don't understand the question why should the OP try this? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: I'm sorry, the question was less clear before, and I misunderstood it.
Now I hope that it's more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use json function to manipulate with vars independently:

```
$f = json_decode(file_get_contents("tt.txt"));
$f['aa']= $_POST['alpha'];
file_put_contents("tt.txt", json_encode($f));
```

and change to bb in 2nd file. To read  just

```
$f = json_decode(file_get_contents("tt.txt"));
echo $f['aa'].' '.$f['bb'];
```